# How to calculate the probability that the value of $S_1$ is $x$ amount higher than vaule of $S_2$

Tags: probability

I have two samples. $S_1$ has mean of $83.17$, with standard deviation of $15.50$. $S_2$ has a mean of $84.00$ and standard deviation of $23.95$. How do you calculate the probability that $S_1$ is greater than $S_2$ by some value $x$ or more?

Answer (score 1):

We need some assumptions which have not been stated. First we need the assumption of **independence**. We will also assume that our random variables have **normal** distribution. The sample sizes are not specified. We will assume they are large. If they are quite small (and specified) the problem can be solved, but is more complicated.

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be independent normally distributed random variables, with means
$\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, and variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ respectively. Let $W=S_1-S_2$. Then $W$ has **normal distribution**, with mean $\mu_1-\mu_2$, and variance $\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2$ (the plus sign here is correct).

Calculate the mean and variance of $W$. Then find the standard deviation of $W$. Since $W$ has normal distribution, you have arrived at a familiar kind of problem.

**Remark:** The standard deviations seem awfully high.